# How does Dictionary use the Equatable protocol in Swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary, hash-collision, hashable, equatable

In order to solve [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31664159/how-to-handle-hash-collisions-for-dictionaries-in-swift), I have been playing around with a custom struct that implements the Hashable Protocol. I'm trying to see how many times the equivalency operator overload (`==`) gets called depending on if there is a hash collision or not when populating a `Dictionary`.

**Update**

[@matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt) wrote a much cleaner example of a custom struct that implements the Hashable protocol and shows how often `hashValue` and `==` get called. I am copying [his code](https://gist.github.com/mattneub/430fef70e3496f5ce6917aa35c98f419) below. To see my original example, check out the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31665802/revisions).

```
struct S : Hashable {
    static func ==(lhs:S,rhs:S) -> Bool {
        print("called == for", lhs.id, rhs.id)
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    let id : Int
    var hashValue : Int {
        print("called hashValue for", self.id)
        return self.id
    }
    init(_ id:Int) {self.id = id}
}
var s = Set<S>()
for i in 1...5 {
    print("inserting", i)
    s.insert(S(i))
}
```

This produces the results:

```
/*
inserting 1
called hashValue for 1
inserting 2
called hashValue for 2
called == for 1 2
called hashValue for 1
called hashValue for 2
inserting 3
called hashValue for 3
inserting 4
called hashValue for 4
called == for 3 4
called == for 1 4
called hashValue for 2
called hashValue for 3
called hashValue for 1
called hashValue for 4
called == for 3 4
called == for 1 4
inserting 5
called hashValue for 5
*/
```

Since Hashable uses Equatable to differentiate hash collisions (I assume anyway), I would expect `func ==()` only to be called when there are hash collisions. However, there are no hash collisions at all in @matt's example above and yet `==` is still being called. In my other experiments forcing hash collisions (see this question's edit history), `==` seemed to be called a random number of times.

What is going on here?

Comment: I hate to give this as an answer, or even a comment, but this is a Swift internal implementation detail. They can optimize the type however they want as long as it conforms to the documented Dictionary APIs. And the documents make no guarantees about how often keys will be checked for equality - they simply require that your provide that `==` interface. I guess we'll know more later this year when Swift becomes open source. Also, see my similar comment to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31664159/how-to-handle-hash-collisions-for-dictionaries-in-swift).

Comment: Here's a simpler test (I think): https://gist.github.com/mattneub/430fef70e3496f5ce6917aa35c98f419 The output makes it very explicit how many times `hashValue` and `==` are called for each insertion.

Comment: @matt, yes, that is a much simpler and clearer test. But now I am more confused than I thought I was. Your example has no hash collisions, right? And yet `==` still gets called. I was under the assumption before that `==` only got called to deal with the hash collision cases.

Comment: Yes, I'm surprised too. I'm thinking of submitting a bug report to bugs.swift.org, unless you want to do it — after all, it's your idea, so I don't want to steal it. (Also, I tried to read the source code but I couldn't figure out where the underlying VariantBuffer stuff was implemented. So I wasn't able to give any answer to your actual question.)

Comment: See what you think: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3330

Comment: @matt, I copied your gist into my question because it was a much better example, and just having a link to it in the comments is not very accessible to future readers. This edit also makes the question match the existing answers better, too.

Comment: Certainly — the gist was public (and was created in response to your question!) and you credited me and linked to the gist, so that's totally in order.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, there's your answer:

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3330?focusedCommentId=19980&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-19980

> What's actually happening:
>
> - We hash a value only once on insertion.
> - We don't use hashes for comparison of elements, only ==. Using hashes for comparison is only reasonable if you store the hashes, but
>     that means more memory usage for every Dictionary. A compromise that
>     needs evaluation.
> - We try to insert the element before evaluating if the Dictionary can fit that element. This is because the element might already be in the
>     Dictionary, in which case we don't need any more capacity.
> - When we resize the Dictionary, we have to rehash everything, because we didn't store the hashes.
>
> So what you're seeing is:
>
> - one hash of the search key
> - some =='s (searching for a space)
> - hashes of every element in the collection (resize)
> - one hash of the search key (actually totally wasteful, but not a big deal considering it only happens after an O reallocation)
> - some =='s (searching for a space in the new buffer)

We all had it totally wrong. They don't use the hashes at all — *only* `==` — to decide whether this is a distinct key. And then there is a second round of calls in the situation where the collection is grown.

Comment: So what is the point of making us implement the Hashable protocol at all when we want to make a custom struct usable in a Dictionary? It seems like the Equatable protocol would be enough.

Comment: @Suragch Basically the hash table is used for _fetching_. But here, we are _storing_, which is a whole different ball of wax.

Comment: *When we resize the Dictionary, we have to rehash everything, because we didn't store the hashes.* can you explain this a bit more? @Suragch Does this apply to the example in the question

Comment: @Honey, this does apply to the example in the question for when that struct is used in a dictionary. However, I honestly still don't understand the point of the hashes. Supposedly they are used for fetching, but if they were never stored, how could they be used to fetch anything? And if they *were* stored (at least long enough to be used to fetch), then why would the the dictionary need to rehash everything for a resize?

Comment: @Suragch did you found any answer to your question (mentioned in the comment above)?

Comment: @Honey, no, I didn't. If Matt has some some more thoughts about it, I would be glad to hear them. Otherwise, I'm just going to leave it as it is That is, I'll keep using the Hashable protocol even though I don't understanding it.

Comment: @Suragch, @Honey It's actually very simple. The dictionary uses hashValue on insertion to determine the bucket to use. (“We hash a value only once on insertion”.) But after that, it uses `==` rather than hashes to compare the new key to the existing elements _within that chosen bucket_.

Comment: @AndreyTarantsov, I don't know what that means. I'd be very glad to see a more detailed answer.

Comment: A dictionary's elements aren't numbered sequentially, so how do you locate an element without iterating over them? With a function that takes a key as an argument and returns the element's address. How can you be sure it will return the correct address? Because it's the same function that was used to set the address! So there's no need to store addresses—the hash function returns them fast, no matter how large the collection. BUT speaking of the collection's size, the function needs this as an argument too. If the size changes, so do the return values—hence the need to 'rehash everything'.

Comment: That was a very simplified explanation (based on my limited understanding) that ignores the reality of hash collisions—where the imperfect nature of hash functions means they occasionally give/return the same address for two different keys—and how that problem is resolved. But hopefully it helps??

Comment: @Kal, thanks for your explanation. Can you add it as a separate answer? It will be more visible to other people that way.

Comment: Okay, done. My comments didn't answer the original question, but I've tried to expand it into something useful. :-)

Comment: @Kal and now please delete the comments.

Answer (score 12):

I'm copying my answer from [bugs.swift.org](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3330) here. It talks about Sets but the details apply to Dictionaries in the same way.

> In hashed collections, collisions can occur whenever the number of buckets is smaller than the keyspace. When you're creating a new Set without specifying a minimum capacity, the set might have only one bucket, so when you're inserting the second element, a collision occurs. The insert method will then decide if the storage should be grown, using something called a load factor. If the storage was grown, the existing elements have to be migrated over to the new storage buffer. That's when you're seeing all those extra calls to hashValue when inserting 4.
>
> The reason you're still seeing more calls to == than you would expect if the number of buckets is equal or higher to the number of elements has to do with an implementation detail of the bucket index calculation. The bits of the hashValue are mixed or "shuffled" before the modulo operation. This is to cut down on excessive collisions for types with bad hash algorithms.

Comment: Thanks. So in a case like this, is it my responsibility to grow the capacity of the collection before adding to it?

Comment: If you know the number of elements ahead of time, I would always pass that value to the initializer. If can potentially save a lot of cycles.

Comment: While this answer is still very useful, I am at least temporarily unchecking it as the accepted answer because of the new info referred to by @matt.

Answer (score 3):

While the question has already been answered, those answers raised some additional questions in the comments. @Suragch asked if I would include my comments in a new answer to help others who might also be confused by the relationship between `Equatable` and `Hashable`. I have to start by saying that I only have a rudimentary understanding of the underlying mechanics, but I'll do my best to explain what I know.

`Equatable` is a fairly simple concept, and we need look no further than the Swift docs for a succinct definition of this protocol:

> **Equatable:** A type that can be compared for value equality.

If a type is equatable, we can compare two instances with `==`. Easy.

`Hashable` is a different story. I actually laughed out loud when I first read the definition of this protocol in the Swift docs:

> **Hashable:** A type that can be hashed into a Hasher to produce an integer hash value.

[image]

If that hasn't cleared it up for you, you're not alone! And anyway, if `==` is used to determine if an instance is truly unique (which it needs to be in a set or when used as a key in a dictionary), why do we need `Hashable` at all? (This is the question @Suragch asked in the comments.)

That question goes to the fundamental nature of hashed collections (or hash tables) like sets and dictionaries. Consider why you might choose a dictionary over an array in the first place. You choose a dictionary when you need to find or refer to an instance by something other than a known index, right? Unlike an array, a dictionary's elements aren't numbered sequentially, which makes finding stuff harder. If all we had was `==`, we'd have to iterate over our dictionary's elements, one by one, and that would get slower and slower as the size of the dictionary increased.

This is where the magic of hash functions come in. The hash function (or hasher) takes a unique key as an argument and returns the element's address. How can you be sure it will return the correct address? Because it's the same function that was used to set that address in the first place! When the dictionary was created, it took each key (or rather, the uniquely identifying properties of each key), mashed them up according to some secret formula, and spat out a number (hash value) for each one, and from those numbers came the new indexes for each element. Later, when you want to look up one of those elements, the hasher gets the same arguments, so it returns the same value. And because all you're doing is calling a function, there's no iteration involved and the results are fast, no matter how large the collection gets.

There's a catch though. No hasher is perfect. Even if you feed it unique arguments, occasionally it may return the same hash value for two completely different elements—a hash collision. When that happens, it needs to check if the two elements really are the same, and it does that, of course, by calling `==`.

But in your example, you manipulated `hashValue` directly (which was the kind of thing people did before [`hash(into:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable/2995575-hash) came along!) and it still called `==`! I mean, in theory, it shouldn't need to do this, since there aren't any collisions. But the answer is there in the [comment quoted by robinkunde](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3330?focusedCommentId=19911&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-19911):

> In hashed collections, collisions can occur whenever the number of buckets is smaller than the keyspace

While generally, we don't need to worry about the implementation details of Swift's built-in hasher function, this particular detail is important… Behind the scenes, the hasher needs another argument, and that is the size of the collection. If the size changes (as it does repeatedly when you're iterating over a range and inserting new elements into the collection), the hasher can either try to shove in more elements than there are indexed slots (or buckets) and you get a collision, or it needs to rehash everything from scratch with enough memory to give every element a unique index. What appears to happen is a combination of both, as the [comment quoted by matt](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3330?focusedCommentId=19980&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-19980) says:

> We try to insert the element before evaluating if the Dictionary can fit that element. This is because the element might already be in the Dictionary, in which case we don't need any more capacity.

---

So that's my attempt at a simpler explanation of hashed collections, the relationship between the hash function and your `==` method, and the reasons for the unexpected behaviour. But this all raises one more question for me… Why do we need to manually declare `Hashable`? Couldn't Apple have baked in some kind of algorithm to synthesize Hashable conformance for all Equatable types? I mean, the [`hash(into:)` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable/2995575-hash) says:

> The components used for hashing must be the same as the components
>   compared in your type’s == operator implementation.

If the components need to be the same, couldn't Swift infer our intention from our implementation of `Equatable` alone? I'm not sure why it couldn't offer such a convenience (similar to the way it offers default initialisers), for those who don't want more control over the details. Perhaps one day Swift will offer this? For now though, they kept them as separate concerns, with `Hashable` inheriting from `Equatable`.

Comment: Nice one! Thanks for leaving an answer. The good part about leaving an answer is that over time if there are mistakes other people will correct you and you learn something. I still don't understand hashing well enough to know if you are right or wrong, but it sounds good and I like your use of analogy to explain a confusing topic.

Comment: No worries. I like analogies too, but upon rereading this one, it felt contrived, so I've rewritten my answer in a way that explains it better I think—and without reference to magic genies. ;-) Writing it helps me cement the concepts too. And yes, I'm always open to being corrected if I'm mistaken about any of the details.